# In iOS6, UIViewController's view position is wrong at app launch

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6

IEverything works fine before iOS 6. I have a `UIViewController` subclass in a `UINavigationController` as usual. Its view is shrinking down about 20 px as if there is another status bar up top. When I push and pop the view back. The view went back to its correct position. I found out it's because `UIViewControllerWrapperView` (got by using `self.view.superview`) frame got wrong somehow in iOS 6.

Doing NSLog in `viewDidAppear`

At app launch ...

```
self.view.frame: {{0, 0}, {768, 891}} // was {{0, 0}, {768, 911}} in iOS5.1
self.view.superview: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x9dddb80; frame = (0 20; 768 891); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9dddc30>> 
// was (0 0; 768 911); in iOS5.1
```

After push and pop view controller (correct value) ...

```
self.view.frame: {{0, 0}, {768, 911}}
self.view.superview: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x9dddb80; frame = (0 0; 768 911); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9dddc30>>
```

It never happens before. How does this appear in iOS 6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my current dirty fix in viewDidAppear.

```
// fix wrong UIViewControllerWrapperView frame by moving up and extending it back
CGRect wvFrame = self.view.superview.frame;
if (wvFrame.origin.y > 0) {
    wvFrame.size.height += wvFrame.origin.y;
    wvFrame.origin.y = 0;
    self.view.superview.frame = wvFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a better fix than accepted. Try to set wantsFullScreenLayout to YES in viewDidLoad.

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```